# Redeeming a 3DS game code without installing the game?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-eshop

A while ago I bought a Friends of Nintendo Humble Bundle, which came with quite a few codes. I still have the codes, as I couldn't find a way through the 3DS to redeem the games without installing them immediately. This is troublesome, as the first one I downloaded was Street Fighter IV, which took up quite a lot of my available blocks, and I am keen to play it for now! Although I could just redeem the code, install the game and then uninstall it, this takes up some time and can be a bit of a nuisance.

I was wondering if there was a way to redeem these codes and not install them, so I can just go to my download software page and install them whenever I want at a later date, similar to how Steam handles the game library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this Nintendo [site](https://eshop.nintendo.net/redeem#/) to redeem codes on a PC. It requires you to log-in with your eShop account, then you can fill in the code. Obviously it will not download the game on your computer, but it should be registered to your account.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot try it because I do not have a code waiting to be used, but this should do what you want

Comment: I just tested it and it works perfectly.